# default label apparently not working in switch statement

Tags: c++, arduino, switch-statement, arduino-c++

I've seen some answers to related posts about this issue, but not exactly an answer to my problem. Here is my code:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
uint8_t RFbuff[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];   
uint8_t RFbuflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;
const int REMOTE = 0; 
String remoteScriptName(){
  String scriptName;
  switch(REMOTE){

    case 1:
      vw_get_message(RFbuff, &RFbuflen);
      String RFSTRBUFF = RFbuff;
      scriptName = RFSTRBUFF; 
      delay(1200);
      break;
    default:
      scriptName = "script"; 
      delay(500); 
    }
  return(scriptName);
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  switch(REMOTE){
    case 1:
      vw_set_rx_pin(8);
      vw_setup(2000);
      vw_rx_start();
      break; 
    default: 
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); 
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); 
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  }
}

void loop(){}
```

In the `remoteScriptName()` function at `switch(REMOTE)` there is `case:` and `default:`. When I upload my code to my Arduino micro it skips the `default` in `switch(REMOTE)`. 
But then at `void setup` I have the same switch statement, but in this case (after uploading the code) it does execute `default:`!

I don't have much experience with `switch()`, so any recommendation is well received.

Comment: if there only one option maybe if-else can help?

Comment: Just to be sure, you know that only one of `case` or `default` parts will be executed right? It's not like that control reaches the `default` body by default...

Comment: Are you sure this is the *actual* code you are executing? Have you perchance tried to simplify it for presentation here and in the process stripped out the actual offending code? How do you know which part is running? Could memory (specifically, the value of `REMOTE`) be corrupted by a bug elsewhere in the program?

Comment: How do you know the default case is skipped?  If it is, then what is returned by `return(scriptName)`?

Comment: Try adding braces in your switch statements.

Comment: This code does not compile.  see [MCVE].  FYI - I use 'stubs' to help this code compile on my desktop for the desktop.  The compiler with enabled errors and warnings can then report a) "error: jump to case label" and b) "note:  crosses initialization of ‘std::string RFSTRBUFF’ "  Adding the braces  to the switch statements fixed these complaints.  There may be other errors.

Comment: @metal My code is pretty large to put it in here and it would not be practical, I can send  a copy of the real code to you if you want. Basically this is one part of the actual code, I'm pretty sure the rest of it doesn't influenciate this part.

Comment: @vsh I'll improve the code over time, so more cases will be add

Comment: @2785528 I don't know why it doesn't compiles to you, it does to me. Thanks for the reported errors!

Comment: @2785528 Ok, so I add the braces and now works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: A compound statement consists of none or more C++ statements enclosed within a set of braces: {}.  For example, in function setup, both 'case' and 'default' statements should be wrapped in braces, because they are to work as a single statement.  I find that braces always help for switch statements, both in readability and in avoiding initialization issues for local auto vars.

Comment: "I don't know why it doesn't compiles to you" Research 'method stubs'. Your code does not compile to run on linux because linux does not have, for instance, digitalWrite. With my stubs providing these missing functions the compile completes. Example stub: " void digitalWrite(int w,int v) { cout << "\n digitalWrite (" << w << "," << v << ")"; } Your code, with my stubs, is less than 100 lines of code, small enough to be a minimal reproducible example.  It also 'runs', in a fashion, and supports some level of debug.

Comment: @2785528 Ok, I think i understood correctly. I don't know if this will be out of topic, but, how you are able to create the stubs? I mean, do you create them in the same file as the rest of the code, or in some sort of configuration file?

Comment: In the same .cpp  as the rest of your code, and I added int main(), and a few other items.  (Such as std::string, an enum with HIGH and LOW, etc.)  The stub need not provide any behavior, it needs only to link properly.  But, I usually have a single cout in a stub (to confirm that it was invoked.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions nudged me to provide a copy of code-with-stubs.

developed on Lubuntu 18.10

using g++ (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008

---

```
#ifndef                 DTB_CHRONO_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_chrono.hh"
using  namespace std::chrono_literals; // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30us
#endif

#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string, std::to_string;

#include <thread>
using std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for;

#ifndef                 DTB_PCKLRT_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_pclkrt.hh"  // class PosixClockRT_t
using  DTB::PClk_t;
#endif

#ifndef                 DTB_SOPS_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_sops.hh" // class StringOps_t
using DTB::Sops_t;
#endif


namespace // anonymous
{
   // functor
   class F838_t  // a UDT (user defined type)
   {
      PClk_t  pclk; // class PosixClockRT_t
      Sops_t  sops; // class StringOps_t

      enum { VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN = 10, LED_BUILTIN, LOW=0x05, HIGH=0x0a };

      uint8_t RFbuff     [VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
      uint8_t RFbuflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;

      const int REMOTE = 0;

   public:
      // ctor and dtor use compiler provided defaults
      int operator()(int argc, char* argv[]) { return exec(argc, argv);  }

   private:

      int exec(int , char** )
         {
            int retVal = 0;
            uint64_t start_ns = pclk.ns();

            setup();
            remoteScriptName();

            cout << "\n\n  F838_t::exec() duration "
                 << sops.digiComma(pclk.ns() - start_ns)
                 << " ns    (" <<  __cplusplus  << ")"
                 << std::endl;
            return retVal;
         }

      void setup()
         {
            pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
            switch(REMOTE)
            {

            case 1:
            {
               vw_set_rx_pin(8);
               vw_setup(2000);
               vw_rx_start();
            }  break;

            default:
            {
               digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
               sleep_for(500ms);  // delay(500);
               digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
               sleep_for(500ms);  // delay(500);
               digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
               sleep_for(500ms);  // delay(500);
               digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
            } break;

            }
         }

      string remoteScriptName()
         {
            string scriptName;
            switch(REMOTE)
            {

            case 1:
            {
               vw_get_message(RFbuff, &RFbuflen);
               //string RFSTRBUFF = RFbuff;
               string RFSTRBUFF;
               for (int i; i < RFbuflen; ++i)
                  RFSTRBUFF += static_cast<char>(RFbuff[i]);
               scriptName = RFSTRBUFF;
               sleep_for(1200ms); //delay(1200);
            }

            break;

            default:
            {
               scriptName = "script";
               sleep_for(500ms); // delay(500);
            }
            }

            return(scriptName);
         } // string remoteScriptName()

      // stubs:
      void pinMode(int led, int v) { cout << "\n  pinMode("
                                          << led << "," << v << ")"; }

      void vw_set_rx_pin(int v) { cout << "\n  vw_set_rx_pin("
                                       << v << ")"; }
      void vw_setup(int v)      { cout << "\n  vw_setup     ("
                                       << v << ")"; }
      void vw_rx_start()        { cout << "\n  vw_rx_start  ()"; }

      void digitalWrite(int w,
                        int v) { cout << "\n  digitalWrite  ("
                                      << w << "," << v << ")"; }

      void vw_get_message(uint8_t*  bf,
                          uint8_t*  ln)
         { cout << "\n  vw_get_message  ("
                << bf << "," <<  *ln << ")"; }

   }; // class F838_t

}  // anonymous namespace

// one line main invokes functor ---------vvvvvvvv
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { return F838_t()(argc, argv); }
```

Note: 142 lines,  only 14 lines of stubs

---

Build output to show compiler options:

```
time make CC='g++ $(m) -O0 ' dumy838 ; ./dumy838

>>>cvs-tools/lmbm/src800/Makefile.i686

R_exe: dumy838.cc
rm -f dumy838
g++ -std=c++17 -m64 -ggdb -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic -Werror=vla 
-Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-compare 
-Wsign-promo -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual
-Wsequence-point -Wdelete-incomplete -Wmaybe-uninitialized 
-Wmisleading-indentation -Wunreachable-code -Wnon-virtual-dtor 
-MMD -MP -O0   dumy838.cc  -o dumy838 
-L../../bag/src -lbag_i686 -lrt -pthread -lncurses -lgmpxx -lgmp

real    0m1.506s
user    0m1.289s
sys 0m0.181s
```

---

Execution output (of stubs) including posix time measurement

```
  pinMode(11,10)
  digitalWrite  (11,5)
  digitalWrite  (11,10)
  digitalWrite  (11,5)
  digitalWrite  (11,10)

  F838_t::exec() duration 2,000,584,200 ns    (201703)

Compilation finished at Sat Dec 28 11:06:06
```

Answer (score 0):

might be inadequate scope, so try on each case

```
//..

     case 1:{
          vw_get_message(RFbuff, &RFbuflen);
          String RFSTRBUFF = RFbuff;
          scriptName = RFSTRBUFF; 
          delay(1200);
       }
          break;
        default:
          scriptName = "script"; 
          delay(500); 
        }
 //...
```